# What is the additive they put in apple juice to change it from cloudy to clear?

Tags: apples, additives

I was told today that my juice was cloudy because they hadn't put the additive in it that makes it clear.

My question is: **What is the additive they put in apple juice to change it from cloudy to clear?**

Comment: Filtered .vs. unfiltered is more accurate. Filtering may or may not involve any additives/filter aids. In making hard cider, I start with brown opaque cider and simply through time and yeast end up with a clear pale yellow end product, without ever putting it through a filter - but a lot of gunk falls to the bottom of the fermenter.

Comment: Commercial production is often similar, just with the addition of large centrifuges to quickly and completely settle out the particulate matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(after reading this: http://www.ncbe.reading.ac.uk/ncbe/protocols/inajam/pdf/jam01.pdf)

They usually use pectinase  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pectinase) to break down pectin molecules to help mechanical filtration.

They also use gelatins to help clump up particules to help mechanical filtering.

Comment: It is important to note that it is the filtration that makes it clear. The additives simply make the filtration more effective with higher yeilds. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vk_ufH6je84&feature=youtu.be&t=2m12s

Comment: That's not 100% true, filtration gets out the big stuff. It'll still be a touch cloudy. They use clarifiers to get the stuff out of suspension and fall to the bottom. Gelatin is one of those, egg white is another, as well as isinglass.

Answer (score 1):

For homebrewers; (making hard cider or even regular)

1. pectic enzyme and pectin for long term clearing
2. irish moss
3. citric acid
4. usually you will re-rack at least 2 times; if not 3;  this means moving from one fermenter to another.
5. You can "polish" with a filter systems; but these are very pricey are not easy to use.

Any homebrew shop will carry the supplies needed.

You could use much the same process for regular cider,

Comment: Patience and a racking or two is all that's needed.

Comment: Agreed; but the pectic enzyme will keep the "solution" from turning cloudy later on.  Many people don't mind the haze; does not effect flavor at all.